# Como centralizar texto rotacionado numa div?

Tags: html, css, html5, css3

Olá amada comunidade!

Estou rotacionando um p dentro de uma div, porem não consigo centralizar ele, estou com bastante dificuldade no css, ja tentei definir um width: e height: para o p, deixei como auto, mas não funciona.

```css
p.vertical
    {
      
     transform: rotate(-90deg);
     -webkit-transform: rotate(-90deg); /* Safari/Chrome */
     -moz-transform: rotate(-90deg); /* Firefox */
     -o-transform: rotate(-90deg); /* Opera */
     -ms-transform: rotate(-90deg); /* IE 9 */
 
     font-size: 17.5px;
     font-family: Arial;
        

    }
```

```html
<div style=' display: inline-block; border-style: solid; border-color: grey; border-width: 2px; border-radius: 4px; padding: 10px;'>
    <div style='background-color: rgb(245,245,245);  display: inline-block; 
    position: relative;
    padding-left: 150px;'> 
      <div style='background-color:blue; width: 150px; display: inline-block; float:left;    
      position: absolute;
      top: 0;
      bottom: 0;
      left: 0;'><p class='vertical'>Como centralizo esse texto baseado na altura da div azul?</p></div>
    
        <div style="float:left;">
          <table border='1' style='background-color: red;'>
            <tr>
              <td>ola</td>
              <td>teste</td>
            </tr>
          </table>  
         </div>
         
         <div style="float:left;">
          <table border='1' style='background-color: red;'>
            <tr>
              <td>ola</td>
              <td>teste</td>
            </tr>
          </table>  
         </div>
         <div style="float:left;">
          <table border='1' style='background-color: red;'>
            <tr>
              <td>ola</td>
              <td>teste</td>
            </tr>
          </table>  
         </div><div style="float:left;">
          <table border='1' style='background-color: red;'>
            <tr>
              <td>ola</td>
              <td>teste</td>
            </tr>
          </table>  
         </div><div style="float:left;">
          <table border='1' style='background-color: red;'>
            <tr>
              <td>ola</td>
              <td>teste</td>
            </tr>
          </table>  
         </div><div style="float:left;">
          <table border='1' style='background-color: red;'>
            <tr>
              <td>ola</td>
              <td>teste</td>
            </tr>
          </table>  
         </div><div style="float:left;">
          <table border='1' style='background-color: red;'>
            <tr>
              <td>ola</td>
              <td>teste</td>
            </tr>
          </table>  
         </div><div style="float:left;">
          <table border='1' style='background-color: red;'>
            <tr>
              <td>ola</td>
              <td>teste</td>
            </tr>
          </table>  
         </div><div style="float:left;">
          <table border='1' style='background-color: red;'>
            <tr>
              <td>ola</td>
              <td>teste</td>
            </tr>
          </table>  
         </div><div style="float:left;">
          <table border='1' style='background-color: red;'>
            <tr>
              <td>ola</td>
              <td>teste</td>
            </tr>
          </table>  
         </div><div style="float:left;">
          <table border='1' style='background-color: red;'>
            <tr>
              <td>ola</td>
              <td>teste</td>
            </tr>
          </table>  
         </div><div style="float:left;">
          <table border='1' style='background-color: red;'>
            <tr>
              <td>ola</td>
              <td>teste</td>
            </tr>
          </table>  
         </div><div style="float:left;">
          <table border='1' style='background-color: red;'>
            <tr>
              <td>ola</td>
              <td>teste</td>
            </tr>
          </table>  
         </div><div style="float:left;">
          <table border='1' style='background-color: red;'>
            <tr>
              <td>ola</td>
              <td>teste</td>
            </tr>
          </table>  
         </div><div style="float:left;">
          <table border='1' style='background-color: red;'>
            <tr>
              <td>ola</td>
              <td>teste</td>
            </tr>
          </table>  
         </div><div style="float:left;">
          <table border='1' style='background-color: red;'>
            <tr>
              <td>ola</td>
              <td>teste</td>
            </tr>
          </table>  
         </div><div style="float:left;">
          <table border='1' style='background-color: red;'>
            <tr>
              <td>ola</td>
              <td>teste</td>
            </tr>
          </table>  
         </div><div style="float:left;">
          <table border='1' style='background-color: red;'>
            <tr>
              <td>ola</td>
              <td>teste</td>
            </tr>
          </table>  
         </div><div style="float:left;">
          <table border='1' style='background-color: red;'>
            <tr>
              <td>ola</td>
              <td>teste</td>
            </tr>
          </table>  
         </div><div style="float:left;">
          <table border='1' style='background-color: red;'>
            <tr>
              <td>ola</td>
              <td>teste</td>
            </tr>
          </table>  
         </div><div style="float:left;">
          <table border='1' style='background-color: red;'>
            <tr>
              <td>ola</td>
              <td>teste</td>
            </tr>
          </table>  
         </div><div style="float:left;">
          <table border='1' style='background-color: red;'>
            <tr>
              <td>ola</td>
              <td>teste</td>
            </tr>
          </table>  
         </div><div style="float:left;">
          <table border='1' style='background-color: red;'>
            <tr>
              <td>ola</td>
              <td>teste</td>
            </tr>
          </table>  
         </div><div style="float:left;">
          <table border='1' style='background-color: red;'>
            <tr>
              <td>ola</td>
              <td>teste</td>
            </tr>
          </table>  
         </div><div style="float:left;">
          <table border='1' style='background-color: red;'>
            <tr>
              <td>ola</td>
              <td>teste</td>
            </tr>
          </table>  
         </div><div style="float:left;">
          <table border='1' style='background-color: red;'>
            <tr>
              <td>ola</td>
              <td>teste</td>
            </tr>
          </table>  
         </div><div style="float:left;">
          <table border='1' style='background-color: red;'>
            <tr>
              <td>ola</td>
              <td>teste</td>
            </tr>
          </table>  
         </div><div style="float:left;">
          <table border='1' style='background-color: red;'>
            <tr>
              <td>ola</td>
              <td>teste</td>
            </tr>
          </table>  
         </div><div style="float:left;">
          <table border='1' style='background-color: red;'>
            <tr>
              <td>ola</td>
              <td>teste</td>
            </tr>
          </table>  
         </div><div style="float:left;">
          <table border='1' style='background-color: red;'>
            <tr>
              <td>ola</td>
              <td>teste</td>
            </tr>
          </table>  
         </div><div style="float:left;">
          <table border='1' style='background-color: red;'>
            <tr>
              <td>ola</td>
              <td>teste</td>
            </tr>
          </table>  
         </div><div style="float:left;">
          <table border='1' style='background-color: red;'>
            <tr>
              <td>ola</td>
              <td>teste</td>
            </tr>
          </table>  
         </div><div style="float:left;">
          <table border='1' style='background-color: red;'>
            <tr>
              <td>ola</td>
              <td>teste</td>
            </tr>
          </table>  
         </div><div style="float:left;">
          <table border='1' style='background-color: red;'>
            <tr>
              <td>ola</td>
              <td>teste</td>
            </tr>
          </table>  
         </div><div style="float:left;">
          <table border='1' style='background-color: red;'>
            <tr>
              <td>ola</td>
              <td>teste</td>
            </tr>
          </table>  
         </div><div style="float:left;">
          <table border='1' style='background-color: red;'>
            <tr>
              <td>ola</td>
              <td>teste</td>
            </tr>
          </table>  
         </div><div style="float:left;">
          <table border='1' style='background-color: red;'>
            <tr>
              <td>ola</td>
              <td>teste</td>
            </tr>
          </table>  
         </div>
         <div style="float:left;">
          <table border='1' style='background-color: red;'>
            <tr>
              <td>ola</td>
              <td>teste</td>
            </tr>
          </table>  
         </div><div style="float:left;">
          <table border='1' style='background-color: red;'>
            <tr>
              <td>ola</td>
              <td>teste</td>
            </tr>
          </table>  
         </div><div style="float:left;">
          <table border='1' style='background-color: red;'>
            <tr>
              <td>ola</td>
              <td>teste</td>
            </tr>
          </table>  
         </div><div style="float:left;">
          <table border='1' style='background-color: red;'>
            <tr>
              <td>ola</td>
              <td>teste</td>
            </tr>
          </table>  
         </div><div style="float:left;">
          <table border='1' style='background-color: red;'>
            <tr>
              <td>ola</td>
              <td>teste</td>
            </tr>
          </table>  
         </div><div style="float:left;">
          <table border='1' style='background-color: red;'>
            <tr>
              <td>ola</td>
              <td>teste</td>
            </tr>
          </table>  
         </div><div style="float:left;">
          <table border='1' style='background-color: red;'>
            <tr>
              <td>ola</td>
              <td>teste</td>
            </tr>
          </table>  
         </div><div style="float:left;">
          <table border='1' style='background-color: red;'>
            <tr>
              <td>ola</td>
              <td>teste</td>
            </tr>
          </table>  
         </div><div style="float:left;">
          <table border='1' style='background-color: red;'>
            <tr>
              <td>ola</td>
              <td>teste</td>
            </tr>
          </table>  
         </div><div style="float:left;">
          <table border='1' style='background-color: red;'>
            <tr>
              <td>ola</td>
              <td>teste</td>
            </tr>
          </table>  
         </div><div style="float:left;">
          <table border='1' style='background-color: red;'>
            <tr>
              <td>ola</td>
              <td>teste</td>
            </tr>
          </table>  
         </div><div style="float:left;">
          <table border='1' style='background-color: red;'>
            <tr>
              <td>ola</td>
              <td>teste</td>
            </tr>
          </table>  
         </div><div style="float:left;">
          <table border='1' style='background-color: red;'>
            <tr>
              <td>ola</td>
              <td>teste</td>
            </tr>
          </table>  
         </div><div style="float:left;">
          <table border='1' style='background-color: red;'>
            <tr>
              <td>ola</td>
              <td>teste</td>
            </tr>
          </table>  
         </div><div style="float:left;">
          <table border='1' style='background-color: red;'>
            <tr>
              <td>ola</td>
              <td>teste</td>
            </tr>
          </table>  
         </div>
         <div style="float:left;">
          <table border='1' style='background-color: red;'>
            <tr>
              <td>ola</td>
              <td>teste</td>
            </tr>
          </table>  
         </div>
         <div style="float:left;">
          <table border='1' style='background-color: red;'>
            <tr>
              <td>ola</td>
              <td>teste</td>
            </tr>
          </table>  
         </div>
         <div style="float:left;">
          <table border='1' style='background-color: red;'>
            <tr>
              <td>ola</td>
              <td>teste</td>
            </tr>
          </table>  
         </div>
         <div style="float:left;">
          <table border='1' style='background-color: red;'>
            <tr>
              <td>ola</td>
              <td>teste</td>
            </tr>
          </table>  
         </div>
         <div style="float:left;">
          <table border='1' style='background-color: red;'>
            <tr>
              <td>ola</td>
              <td>teste</td>
            </tr>
          </table>  
         </div><div style="float:left;">
          <table border='1' style='background-color: red;'>
            <tr>
              <td>ola</td>
              <td>teste</td>
            </tr>
          </table>  
         </div>
         <div style="float:left;">
          <table border='1' style='background-color: red;'>
            <tr>
              <td>ola</td>
              <td>teste</td>
            </tr>
          </table>  
         </div>
         <div style="float:left;">
          <table border='1' style='background-color: red;'>
            <tr>
              <td>ola</td>
              <td>teste</td>
            </tr>
          </table>  
         </div>
         <div style="float:left;">
          <table border='1' style='background-color: red;'>
            <tr>
              <td>ola</td>
              <td>teste</td>
            </tr>
          </table>  
         </div>
         <div style="float:left;">
          <table border='1' style='background-color: red;'>
            <tr>
              <td>ola</td>
              <td>teste</td>
            </tr>
          </table>  
         </div><div style="float:left;">
          <table border='1' style='background-color: red;'>
            <tr>
              <td>ola</td>
              <td>teste</td>
            </tr>
          </table>  
         </div>
         <div style="float:left;">
          <table border='1' style='background-color: red;'>
            <tr>
              <td>ola</td>
              <td>teste</td>
            </tr>
          </table>  
         </div><div style="float:left;">
          <table border='1' style='background-color: red;'>
            <tr>
              <td>ola</td>
              <td>teste</td>
            </tr>
          </table>  
         </div><div style="float:left;">
          <table border='1' style='background-color: red;'>
            <tr>
              <td>ola</td>
              <td>teste</td>
            </tr>
          </table>  
         </div><div style="float:left;">
          <table border='1' style='background-color: red;'>
            <tr>
              <td>ola</td>
              <td>teste</td>
            </tr>
          </table>  
         </div><div style="float:left;">
          <table border='1' style='background-color: red;'>
            <tr>
              <td>ola</td>
              <td>teste</td>
            </tr>
          </table>  
         </div>
         
    </div>
  </div>
```

Tenho uma duvida também relativo ao CSS, porque o porque não respeita o tamanho da div azul, se ele é filho?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Primeiro coloca `text-align:center;` no texto.

Depois coloca essas classes no box-azul: `display: flex; justify-content: center; align-items: center;`

Veja como fica no exemplo abaixo:

```css
p.vertical
    {
      
     transform: rotate(-90deg);
     -webkit-transform: rotate(-90deg); /* Safari/Chrome */
     -moz-transform: rotate(-90deg); /* Firefox */
     -o-transform: rotate(-90deg); /* Opera */
     -ms-transform: rotate(-90deg); /* IE 9 */
 
     font-size: 17.5px;
     font-family: Arial;
     text-align: center;
        

    }
```

```html
<div style=' display: inline-block; border-style: solid; border-color: grey; border-width: 2px; border-radius: 4px; padding: 10px;'>
                <div style='background-color: rgb(245,245,245);  display: inline-block; 
                position: relative;
                padding-left: 150px;'> 
                  <div style='background-color:blue; width: 150px; display: inline-block; float:left;    
                  position: absolute;
                  top: 0;
                  bottom: 0;
                  left: 0;
                  display: flex;
                  justify-content: center;
                  align-items: center;'>
                  
                  <p class='vertical'>Como centralizo esse texto baseado na altura da div azul?</p></div>
                

                     <div style="float:left;">
                      <table border='1' style='background-color: red;'>
                        <tr>
                          <td>ola</td>
                          <td>teste</td>
                        </tr>
                      </table>  
                     </div><div style="float:left;">
                      <table border='1' style='background-color: red;'>
                        <tr>
                          <td>ola</td>
                          <td>teste</td>
                        </tr>
                      </table>  
                     </div><div style="float:left;">
                      <table border='1' style='background-color: red;'>
                        <tr>
                          <td>ola</td>
                          <td>teste</td>
                        </tr>
                      </table>  
                     </div><div style="float:left;">
                      <table border='1' style='background-color: red;'>
                        <tr>
                          <td>ola</td>
                          <td>teste</td>
                        </tr>
                      </table>  
                     </div><div style="float:left;">
                      <table border='1' style='background-color: red;'>
                        <tr>
                          <td>ola</td>
                          <td>teste</td>
                        </tr>
                      </table>  
                     </div><div style="float:left;">
                      <table border='1' style='background-color: red;'>
                        <tr>
                          <td>ola</td>
                          <td>teste</td>
                        </tr>
                      </table>  
                     </div><div style="float:left;">
                      <table border='1' style='background-color: red;'>
                        <tr>
                          <td>ola</td>
                          <td>teste</td>
                        </tr>
                      </table>  
                     </div><div style="float:left;">
                      <table border='1' style='background-color: red;'>
                        <tr>
                          <td>ola</td>
                          <td>teste</td>
                        </tr>
                      </table>  
                     </div>
                     <div style="float:left;">
                      <table border='1' style='background-color: red;'>
                        <tr>
                          <td>ola</td>
                          <td>teste</td>
                        </tr>
                      </table>  
                     </div><div style="float:left;">
                      <table border='1' style='background-color: red;'>
                        <tr>
                          <td>ola</td>
                          <td>teste</td>
                        </tr>
                      </table>  
                     </div><div style="float:left;">
                      <table border='1' style='background-color: red;'>
                        <tr>
                          <td>ola</td>
                          <td>teste</td>
                        </tr>
                      </table>  
                     </div><div style="float:left;">
                      <table border='1' style='background-color: red;'>
                        <tr>
                          <td>ola</td>
                          <td>teste</td>
                        </tr>
                      </table>  
                     </div><div style="float:left;">
                      <table border='1' style='background-color: red;'>
                        <tr>
                          <td>ola</td>
                          <td>teste</td>
                        </tr>
                      </table>  
                     </div><div style="float:left;">
                      <table border='1' style='background-color: red;'>
                        <tr>
                          <td>ola</td>
                          <td>teste</td>
                        </tr>
                      </table>  
                     </div><div style="float:left;">
                      <table border='1' style='background-color: red;'>
                        <tr>
                          <td>ola</td>
                          <td>teste</td>
                        </tr>
                      </table>  
                     </div><div style="float:left;">
                      <table border='1' style='background-color: red;'>
                        <tr>
                          <td>ola</td>
                          <td>teste</td>
                        </tr>
                      </table>  
                     </div><div style="float:left;">
                      <table border='1' style='background-color: red;'>
                        <tr>
                          <td>ola</td>
                          <td>teste</td>
                        </tr>
                      </table>  
                     </div><div style="float:left;">
                      <table border='1' style='background-color: red;'>
                        <tr>
                          <td>ola</td>
                          <td>teste</td>
                        </tr>
                      </table>  
                     </div><div style="float:left;">
                      <table border='1' style='background-color: red;'>
                        <tr>
                          <td>ola</td>
                          <td>teste</td>
                        </tr>
                      </table>  
                     </div><div style="float:left;">
                      <table border='1' style='background-color: red;'>
                        <tr>
                          <td>ola</td>
                          <td>teste</td>
                        </tr>
                      </table>  
                     </div><div style="float:left;">
                      <table border='1' style='background-color: red;'>
                        <tr>
                          <td>ola</td>
                          <td>teste</td>
                        </tr>
                      </table>  
                     </div><div style="float:left;">
                      <table border='1' style='background-color: red;'>
                        <tr>
                          <td>ola</td>
                          <td>teste</td>
                        </tr>
                      </table>  
                     </div><div style="float:left;">
                      <table border='1' style='background-color: red;'>
                        <tr>
                          <td>ola</td>
                          <td>teste</td>
                        </tr>
                      </table>  
                     </div>
                     <div style="float:left;">
                      <table border='1' style='background-color: red;'>
                        <tr>
                          <td>ola</td>
                          <td>teste</td>
                        </tr>
                      </table>  
                     </div>
                     <div style="float:left;">
                      <table border='1' style='background-color: red;'>
                        <tr>
                          <td>ola</td>
                          <td>teste</td>
                        </tr>
                      </table>  
                     </div>
                     <div style="float:left;">
                      <table border='1' style='background-color: red;'>
                        <tr>
                          <td>ola</td>
                          <td>teste</td>
                        </tr>
                      </table>  
                     </div>
                     <div style="float:left;">
                      <table border='1' style='background-color: red;'>
                        <tr>
                          <td>ola</td>
                          <td>teste</td>
                        </tr>
                      </table>  
                     </div>
                     <div style="float:left;">
                      <table border='1' style='background-color: red;'>
                        <tr>
                          <td>ola</td>
                          <td>teste</td>
                        </tr>
                      </table>  
                     </div><div style="float:left;">
                      <table border='1' style='background-color: red;'>
                        <tr>
                          <td>ola</td>
                          <td>teste</td>
                        </tr>
                      </table>  
                     </div>
                     <div style="float:left;">
                      <table border='1' style='background-color: red;'>
                        <tr>
                          <td>ola</td>
                          <td>teste</td>
                        </tr>
                      </table>  
                     </div>
                     <div style="float:left;">
                      <table border='1' style='background-color: red;'>
                        <tr>
                          <td>ola</td>
                          <td>teste</td>
                        </tr>
                      </table>  
                     </div>
                     <div style="float:left;">
                      <table border='1' style='background-color: red;'>
                        <tr>
                          <td>ola</td>
                          <td>teste</td>
                        </tr>
                      </table>  
                     </div>
                     <div style="float:left;">
                      <table border='1' style='background-color: red;'>
                        <tr>
                          <td>ola</td>
                          <td>teste</td>
                        </tr>
                      </table>  
                     </div><div style="float:left;">
                      <table border='1' style='background-color: red;'>
                        <tr>
                          <td>ola</td>
                          <td>teste</td>
                        </tr>
                      </table>  
                     </div>
                     <div style="float:left;">
                      <table border='1' style='background-color: red;'>
                        <tr>
                          <td>ola</td>
                          <td>teste</td>
                        </tr>
                      </table>  
                     </div><div style="float:left;">
                      <table border='1' style='background-color: red;'>
                        <tr>
                          <td>ola</td>
                          <td>teste</td>
                        </tr>
                      </table>  
                     </div><div style="float:left;">
                      <table border='1' style='background-color: red;'>
                        <tr>
                          <td>ola</td>
                          <td>teste</td>
                        </tr>
                      </table>  
                     </div><div style="float:left;">
                      <table border='1' style='background-color: red;'>
                        <tr>
                          <td>ola</td>
                          <td>teste</td>
                        </tr>
                      </table>  
                     </div><div style="float:left;">
                      <table border='1' style='background-color: red;'>
                        <tr>
                          <td>ola</td>
                          <td>teste</td>
                        </tr>
                      </table>  
                     </div>
                     
                </div>
              </div>
```

Comment: exatamente isso, aonde eu posso estudar mais css? to apanhando quando nao uso bootstrap

Comment: To ligado como é, quando eu comecei não tinha esses frameworks, eu aprendia era no tapa haha. Cara leia muito, principalmente as documentações W3C, não fica só vendo vídeo no Youtube não! Entra nesse site e sai clicando e lendo tudo que vc puder, estude os exemplos, e vai tentando copia-los ou aplica-los em outras situações. Para trabalhar com CSS tem que ter certa criatividade... https://css-tricks.com/ se precisar de algo em português me fala. As vezes vale a pena algum curso tb, indico esse! https://www.origamid.com/